# PHP dropdown menu options

Tags: php, html

Im trying to make a dropdown menu in php however I cannot seem to get more than one option appear in the menu I think it may something to do with size of the class list array, how do I fix this? is there a better way of solving this issue? Below is my code:

```
    <?php
     class Classlist { 
  private $classCount = 0;

 public function show() { 
 $count = null;
 $classCount = $this-> _countClass($count);


 for($i = 0; $i < $classCount + 1; $i++){
  $content = $this-> _classList();
 }
  return $content;
}

private function _countClass(){
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$link = mysqli_connect('*******','******','*******#','------');
 $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM student_class WHERE user_id = '$user_id';") or die(mysql_error($link));
 $classList = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $classList[$row['class_id']][] = $row;
}
 return sizeof($classList);
}

 private function _classList(){
 $link = mysqli_connect('*******','******','*******#','------');


$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$result = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM student_class WHERE  user_id =   '$userID';") or die(mysql_error());
$classes = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $classes[$row['class_id']][] = $row;
}
 foreach($classes as $c_id => $value){
   $className = array();
   $class_id = json_encode($c_id);
   $query_classname = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT class_name FROM classes WHERE class_id ='$c_id';") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_classname)){

    $className[$row['class_name']][] = $row;
}
}
 $content = '';
foreach($className  as $name => $value){
   $content .='<option value ="'. $name.'">'. $name.'</option>';
}
return $content;    
  }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't worry, one option is better than zero option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are emptying $className array on every iteration of foreach($classes as $c_id => $value) loop, So you end up with one item inside the array (actually the last item). Put $className = array() outside the loop.

```
$className = array();
foreach($classes as $c_id => $value){
    $class_id = json_encode($c_id);
    $query_classname = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT class_name FROM classes WHERE class_id ='$c_id';") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_classname)){
         $className[$row['class_name']][] = $row;
     }
}
```